Handle another batch in a batch class execute method
Refer to below code. I try to create each account with 1000 contacts of it.
The amount of account can be handled by batch so I can set numberOfAccountsToCreate more than 10000.
But the amount of contacts created will have below error:

System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001

Method I have tried :

Declared  contacts at class level then pass it to another batch class in finish method.


I got error Batchable instance is too big.


Call Queueable class in execute method. I got error Too many queueable jobs added to the queue.

Is there any way to solve such an issue?
public class AccountBatchCreator implements Database.Batchable<String> {
    private Integer numberOfAccountsToCreate;  

    public AccountBatchCreator(Integer numberOfAccountsToCreate) {
        this.numberOfAccountsToCreate = numberOfAccountsToCreate;
    }  

    public Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        List<String> accountNames = new List<String>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfAccountsToCreate; i++) {
            accountNames.add('Test Account --+' + i);
        }

        return accountNames;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<String> scope) {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        for (String accountName : scope) {
            accounts.add(new Account(Name = accountName));
        }

        insert accounts;  

        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                contacts.add(new Contact(
                    AccountId = account.Id,
                    AssistantName = 'test contact',
                    LastName = 'te',
                    FirstName='st'
                ));
            }
        }

        insert contacts;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        System.debug('Batch processing completed.');
    }
}

Code ran in anonymous window.
Integer numberOfAccountsToCreate = 10; 

AccountBatchCreator batch = new AccountBatchCreator(numberOfAccountsToCreate);  

Database.executeBatch(batch, 200);  


Why not simply set number of accounts to create per chunk to a smaller value such that number of accounts * (number of contacts + 1) is less than 10000?

Yes , this will not exceed the Governor Limits. But I want to handle the issue that will exceed the Governor Limits.

This is how you handle it... why make your code more complex than it need be, when you can simply pass in an appropriate chunk size to the Database.executeBatch call?

Yes ,this is a sample code to describe the issue. In some scenario, I can't keep changing the scope size. Even if the scope size is small ,  I have other query result that  * accounts then to insert may exceed the limit.
I want to resolve this situation, not just this code. Sorry for not describing it clearly.

You can address this by providing a method that you use, instead of directly calling Database.executeBatch, when wanting to run the batch, where it performs a necessary calculation to determine the optimal batch chunk size. Alternatively, swap to using Queueable with a Finalizer implementation so you can react to governor limit issues and perform a binary chop to determine a working "chunk size" for the Queueable to process.
